# Drupal 6 hook for field access

Tags: 6, hooks, entities

I want to use my own code to determine if a user has edit access on certain fields.  [`hook_field_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) for Drupal 7 looks right.  Is there a comparable hook for Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hook with exactly the same name exists for CCK in Drupal 6, it just doesn't seem to be all that well documented.

It's invoked from the [`content_access()`](http://api.lullabot.com/content_access) function and has the following signature:

```
function MYMODULE_field_access($op, $field, $account = NULL, $node = NULL) {

}
```